# Finished first Marathon training. Now what?

Tags: running, training, marathon

This weekend I'll be running my first marathon. **So, what comes next?**

I know I shouldn't stop running (and don't want to).
I followed a very detailed training plan, but haven't found a *post-race* plan.
**Is there such thing as a post-race plan?**

So far I know I'll run 3k/2mi (as slow as I feel comfortable) the day after the race, but that's all I got.

Some more specific questions would be:

- Is it too much if I run a half-marathon one week later?
- Should I still do long-runs every weekend?

  - What distance should I go for?
- How long should I try to recover before signing up for my next marathon?

Comment: This is on-topic here, but have you considered checking out [Fitness SE](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marathon)?

Comment: @edmastermind29 I hadn't considered it, but after reading [tag:marathon] and [tag:running] tags here and over there, the ones on Sports.SE are closer to what I expect to have answered.

Comment: Great. Welcome. Here's to helping you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hal Higdon has a ton of training plans.  Here's his one for multiple marathons.

http://www.halhigdon.com/training/51153/Marathon-Multiple-Marathons-Training-Program

The specific answers to your questions is to do what you want while listening to your body.

Higdon's plan for two marathons two weeks apart has a 1 -2 hour run on the weekend in between.  That could be an half-marathon.  It's hard to tell before your marathon if your body will feel up to a Half a week later, but if it is, a Half sounds like fun.

If you have time to keep up with the long runs while still doing shorter runs in the week, I would recommend keeping up with them.  You don't want to be doing 2 -3 hour runs on the weekends and nothing during the week.  And then when you sign up for your next marathon, you're not starting from scratch.

You'll want to sign up for your next marathon about an hour or two after you cross the finish line.  Go for it.  Read the multiple marathon training plan and work out a schedule using it as a guide.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

What I have found, personally is that if your marathon does not go as well as planned, you can treat it as one more long training run and then taper again for another marathon in a couple of weeks.

But listen to your body. If you are feeling up to it, keep going.

It is great to take a break, but do not stop entirely, make sure to keep running so as not to lose all that base you built up. Then go out and just enjoy running for fun with no specific goals.